# Rēapse or reāpse?

Tags: etymology, old-latin

**reapse** is a univerbation of **rē** and **eāpse**, the archaic form of **ipsā**. It is macronized as **rēapse** in Lewis & Short's and OLD, but as **reāpse** in Gaffiot, Allen & Greenough's *New Latin Grammar* and also Wiktionary.

In most cases, the former one of two adjacent vowels is short. However **e** and **a** in this word both seem to come from long vowels (**r[*ē*] e[*ā*]pse**). Are there any evidence for the length of vowels in this word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe rēapse is an error, probably just a typo. It doesn't seem to be mentioned in [Notes on Lewis and Short's Latin-English Lexicon](https://www.jstor.org/stable/287803) (Alex. Leeper, 1899), but you can see from that article's length that there are a number of other errors.

The etymology clearly calls for a long *ā*, and I don't know of any compelling reason to reject that.

Reapse is relatively uncommon.

I found only one example in verse in the PHI Latin texts corpus, and Cairnarvon pointed out to me in a comment that this is actually an emendation of the manuscript reading ⟨reab⟩ (so it is fairly, although not entirely, circular to use it as evidence for the scansion of this word).

> Titus Maccius Plautus, Truculentus 815
>
> Anc. Idem istuc ipsa, etsi tu taceas, **reab<se>** experta intellego.

Per [The Meters of Roman Comedy](https://romancomedy.wustl.edu/other.html), the meter here is
tr7 ([trochaic septenarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochaic_septenarius)).

My attempt at scanning the line is as follows:

Ĭdem ĭs-tuc i͞psa, e͞t|sī tū tăcĕ-a͞s, || **rea͞pse** e͞x-pe͞r-ta i͞n|te͞llĕgo.

uu x - - | - - uu - || - - - - | - u -

(I'm not sure whether the second syllable of "istuc" is long or short, but it doesn't make a difference)

It seems that "reap-" would scan as one syllable here. A short vowel in the first syllable of a word may be pronounced non-syllabically in certain circumstances in Plautus (as I remember it, the conditions are that it should be directly followed by a vowel that is either long by nature or in a closed syllable, i.e. "long by position"). This can be categorized broadly as a type of "synizesis", although the conditions in which it occurs are different from the conditions later Lation poets use word-internally.

Comment: Note, however, that *reapse* in this verse is an emendation by Joachim Camerarius; the codices have *re ab*. I don't think we have any metrical evidence one way or the other.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: Oh, thanks! Yeah, in that case, it's not really independent evidence.